# Grunt watch with template syntax

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to configure Grunt to watch my less files, but it's getting into some sort of recursive error loop.

Here's the relevant parts of `Gruntfile.js`:

```
watch: {
    ...
    less: {
        files: ['<%= less.dev.files %>'],
        tasks: ['less:dev']
    }
},

less: {
    options: {
        paths: 'www/css',
        strictMath: true,
        strictUnits: true
    },
    dev: {
        options: {
            cleancss: false
        },
        files: {
            'www/css/main.css' : 'www/css/main.less'
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

As soon as I runt `grunt watch:less` in my terminal, I get this:

> Running "watch:less" (watch) task
>   Waiting...Warning: Object # has no method 'indexOf'
>
> Running "watch:less" (watch) task
>   Waiting...Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Maximum call stack size exceeded).
>   Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (An error occurred while processing a template (Maximum call stack size exceeded).).
>   Warning: Object # has no method 'indexOf'

Which repeats for quite awhile until it bails out.

It appears `<%= less.dev.files %>` is confusing it. Why? Is that not the right syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`less.dev.files` is an object. Since you only have one config, I recommend using the src/dest pattern and reference that instead:

```
watch: {
  less: {
    files: ['<%= less.dev.src %>'],
    tasks: ['less']
  }
},
less: {
  dev: {
    src: 'www/css/main.less'
    dest: 'www/css/main.css'
  }
}
```

Otherwise you would need to reference the key within the object with:

```
'<%= less.dev.files["www/css/main.css"] %>'
```